# Crystal Report date parameter from stored procedure always string

Tags: crystal-reports

My date parameter alway string type in crystal report

[My stored procedure parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkTtb.png)

[Parameter in Crystal Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxzJw.png)

Thanks.

Comment: In Stored procedure change datatype to smalldatetime

Comment: Create a formula field in CrystalReport to covert string to date using CDate. Use this formula field in designer

Comment: Mahendra thank
Mukul Varshney thank it work